# How do i add sdkmanager to my environments variable path?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, sdk

i am running 'flutter doctor --anroid-licenses' but it says I need to update my sdk by using 'sdkmanager --update' but when I do, I keep getting a 'sdkmanager: command not found' reply.

Answer (score 2):

`sdkmanager` is not added to the `env` path. One way to access it is using `Command Prompt`.

Open `CMD` and execute like this (old path):

```
C:\Path_To_Android_Sdk\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --update
```

New Path:

```
%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin
```

Or add it to `env` path by following these steps:

1. Search and Open "Edit this systems environment variables".
2. Click on Environment Variables at the bottom.
3. Select and Edit **Path** variable.
4. Add a semicolon if one doesn't exists.
5. Paste the folder path such as "C:\Path_To_Android_Sdk\sdk\tools\bin"
6. Save and exit the windows.
7. Restart CMD to load new path.

Comment: The location of SDKManager.bat after installing Android Studio -> More Actions -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools tab-> Android Studio Command-Line Tools (latest) is `%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin`. It is not added by default in environment variables and you have to add it yourself.